# C++ Is there a way how to simulate union behavior between child and parent classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, unions

is there a way how to simulate union behavior? See following code:

```
// this is ideal interface, which I would like to simulate
struct IdealInterface{
  union{
    struct{float r,g,b;};
    struct{float x,y,z;};
  };
};

// this is real parent object I should not change
struct Parent{
  float r, g, b;
};

// this interface has ok behavior,
// but sizeof(Child0) != sizeof(Parent)
// which causes problems
struct Child0:public Parent{
  float & x, & y, & z;
  Child0() : Parent(), x(r), y(g), z(b){ };
};

// this has ok size, but interface is different
struct Child1:public Parent{
  float & x(){ return r; }
  float & y(){ return g; }
  float & z(){ return b; }
};
```

So as described, I should keep Parent class, and I should derive my child class from Parent. I should not create different types and play with the type conversions. Thus, is it possible to create derived class (form Parent) with the same interface as IdealInterface class has?

Comment: `sizeof(child0)` should not equal `sizeof(parent)`. It has three iVars that the parent doesn't. Event pointers and references take up space.

Comment: also, why do you need inheritance for this problem? If your children only have accessors and mutators, then move those into the parent and don't bother with inheritance.

Comment: and for my last question, why not just use `IdealInterface` if it already has everything you want to accomplish?

Comment: Note that reading from a different union member than the one written is *undefined behavior* anyway, so making the union compile still probably won't make it do what you desire.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Looks like XY problem to me. What are you trying to achieve? Is this a homework or a real-world priblem?

Comment: Note there's no guarantee that sizeof(parent)==sizeof(child) even if child adds nothing whatsoever to parent.

Comment: @n.m. Isn't that only the case when you have `virtual` members?

Comment: @Freddy I don't think an implementation is forbidden from adding its own invisible members for any purpose (e.g. better debugging). Not having a virtual dtor is suspicious anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

Firstly, *I have some words for commentators.* I asked a pretty straight question. What I got? For example answers about sizeof properties, which were not posed (btw, yeah in this case I have guarantee about sizeof - this is c++, not a kind of today common wild language).

*Why I cannot use IdealInterface.* Problem is more complex. I want to edit bigger pack of code with introduced constraints and dependencies. Thus this is the question and I cannot redefine question, however it implies simpler solution.

Answer: **NO**, it is not possible.

Why? It is based on properties of anonymous structs and unions.

Nearest approach: For my purpose, nearest approach is to use memory model as parameter.

```
struct BASIC_MEMORY_MODEL{
    float x, y, z;
    BASIC_MEMORY_MODEL() :x(), y(), z(){}
};

struct ADVANCED_MEMORY_MODEL{
    union{
        struct { float x, y, z; };
        struct { float r, g, b; };
    };
    ADVANCED_MEMORY_MODEL() :x(), y(), z(){}
};

template<typename MEMORY_MODEL = BASIC_MEMORY_MODEL>
struct ParentBase : public MEMORY_MODEL{};

typedef ParentBase<> Parent;

struct Child : public ParentBase < ADVANCED_MEMORY_MODEL > {};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean identical behavior to a `union` then no, not without actually using a `union`.

You could always just hide the underlying data:

```
class Vertex
{

 Vertex();
 Vertex(float,float,float);

 float& x() { return r;}
 float& y() { return g;}
 float& z() { return b;}
 float& r() { return r;}
 float& g() { return g;}
 float& b() { return b;}

 void r(float rComponent) { this->r = rComponent; }
 ...

 private:
   float r, g, b;
}
```

However, the downside to this approach is you must call the methods vs. accessing the underlying variable like you can do with the union.

If you want:

```
Vertex v;
v.x = 1.0f
```

Then you would want to use a union.